# Simple css - text in paragraph is going outside the box

Tags: css

I have set width and height for a paragraph element, but text is still going outside the box instead filling up the element.Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
p {  height: 500px;
     width: 800px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>
                            tekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekstteksttekst    
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How to make that text stay inside p elements box?

Comment: darkajax has the fix for you but the text you posted is a very unlikely use case, unless your system is expected to output long strings without spaces.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with the text inside your `<p>` element is that it's a single HUGE word, so you should use something like: `word-wrap: break-word;` and that should make it fit...

Answer (score 2):

You can use this style:

```
p {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

this will not break the word as in [@darkajax's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15295995/782609), but add a horizontal scroll bar.